# Google Maps markers saving form data in an array

Tags: arrays, json, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I apologize, but this is a beginners questions (I'm one). I'm working on a jQuery Mobile app, and I'm struggling with a form data that I'm trying to save. The map works fine, and the markers, but this is the issue. I added two event listeners:

JS

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'click',

   function (e) {
   addLocations(this.getPosition());
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, 'dragend',

   function () {
   google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'click');
   });
```

This opens a popup showing where some data is entered. This is the popup

```
     <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" data-transition="slidedown" data-position-to="#homeHeader" data-overlay-theme="e">
<form id="locDataColletion">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px">
         <h3>Please Enter Location Info</h3>

        <label for="location">Location:</label>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="" placeholder="Location Name" data-theme="a">
        <label for="note">Note:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="note" value="" placeholder="Enter Notes or Reminder" data-theme="a"></textarea>
```

Add Location   Cancel

The popup opens as expected, but now is when everything goes wrong. Once the submit button is hit, I would like to save the form data and location in an array. This is the JS

```
function addLocations(location) {

$('#popup-anchor').trigger("click");

$('#location, #note').val("");
$('#latitude').html('<b>Latitude: </b>' + location.lat());
$('#longitude').html(' <b>Longitude: </b>' + location.lng());

$(document).on('submit', '#locDataColletion', function (event) {
    pointCount++;
    pointsArray.push({
        'Location': $('#location').val(),
            'addedPoint': pointCount,
            'lat': location.lat(),
            'lng': location.lng(),
            'Note': $('#note').val()
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(pointsArray));
});}
```

Once I submit the form information the data is correctly pushed to "pointsArray", but when I select another marker and do the same operation, the first entry is duplicated automatically. This is an example of the result:

```
[
{
    "Location": "aa",
    "addedPoint": 1,
    "lat": 25.889457707750903,
    "lng": -80.29134750366211,
    "Note": "bb"
},
{
    "Location": "bb",
    "addedPoint": 2,
    "lat": 25.889457707750903,
    "lng": -80.29134750366211,
    "Note": "bb"
},
{
    "Location": "bb",
    "addedPoint": 3,
    "lat": 25.8842454748656,
    "lng": -80.29490947723389,
    "Note": "bb"
}]
```

As you can see, I entered "aa", submit the data, and everything went fine, but when I enter "bb", two entries were created, one pulled data from the previous entry and the second one with the correct location of the second marker. I know this is a very long question, but it is driving crazy. If more detail are needed for a solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying `submit` event listener inside `addLocations` function. Whenever you run that function, you duplicate the code inside `submit`.

You can leave it where it is, just make sure you remove previous binding `.off()` and then rebind `.on()`.

```
$(document)
    .off('submit', '#locDataColletion')
    .on('submit', '#locDataColletion', function (event) {
    // your code
});
```

Or, move it outside `addLocations` function and pass `location` object in a global variable.

```
var pointCount = 0,
    pointsArray = [],
    locationObject;

function addLocations(location) {
    locationObject = location;
    $("#popupMenu").popup("open"); // open popup

    $('#location, #note').val("");
    $('#latitude').html('<b>Latitude: </b>' + location.lat());
    $('#longitude').html(' <b>Longitude: </b>' + location.lng());
}

$(document).on('submit', '#locDataColletion', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from reloading
    pointCount++;
    pointsArray.push({
        'Location': $('#location').val(),
            'addedPoint': pointCount,
            'lat': locationObject.lat(),
            'lng': locationObject.lng(),
            'Note': $('#note').val()
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(pointsArray));

    $(this).closest(".ui-popup").popup("close"); // close popup
});
```

I test your code and it works well; check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmhk1y16/3/).

Comment: This worked perfectly! I went ahead and used the second option. Thanks a lot!